# `coerce` and instantiation of type variables

Tags: haskell, unification, coerce

Consider the following GHCi session:

```
>:set -XTypeApplications
>import Data.Map.Strict
>import GHC.Exts
>newtype MySet a = MySet (Map a ())
>let member' :: Ord a => a -> MySet a -> Bool; member' = coerce member

<interactive>:21:57: error:
    * Couldn't match representation of type `a0' with that of `()'
        arising from a use of `coerce'
    * In the expression: coerce member
      In an equation for member': member' = coerce member
>let member' :: Ord a => a -> MySet a -> Bool; member' = coerce (member @_ @())
```

I have a hunch of what's going on here: The type-checker needs to satisfy `Coercible (Ord a => a -> Map a b -> Bool) (Ord a => a -> MySet a -> Bool)` and isn't able to instantiate `b` in this constraint to `()`.

Is there a more elegant way than to do this with `-XTypeApplications`?

Edit: I'm especially looking for solutions that deal with many occurences of `MySet a` in the type, for example `union :: Ord a => MySet a -> MySet a -> MySet a`.

Comment: How about `member' k s = member k (coerce s)`?

Comment: Good thinking, But this gets quite verbose for `union` (where `MySet` occurs multiple times in the type) and is not possible at all for `fromList`.

Comment: I think this might be considerable a bug in GHC, and certainly worth a ticket. Or talk to Richard in Oxford :-)

Comment: @JoachimBreitner, I suspect this would be rather hard to fix. See my answer. Of course, you and Richard both know much more than I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
member :: Ord a => a -> Map a b -> Bool
member' :: Ord a => a -> MySet a -> Bool
```

GHC needs to accept

```
Coercible (Map a b) (MySet a)
```

It sees that

```
Coercible (MySet a) (Map a ())
```

which leaves it needing

```
Coercible (Map a ()) (Map a b)
```

which leads to

```
Coercible () b
```

But what is `b`? It's ambiguous. In this case, it doesn't matter what `b` is, because by parametricity, `member` can't possibly care. So it would be perfectly reasonable to choose `b ~ ()` and resolve the coercion trivially. But GHC generally doesn't perform such a parametricity analysis in type inference. I suspect it might be tricky to change that. Most especially, any time the type inference "guesses", there's a risk it might guess wrong and block up inference somewhere else. It's a big can of worms.

As for your problem, I don't have a good solution. When you have several functions with similar patterns, you can abstract them out, but you'll still face significant annoyance.

Comment: That sounds kind-of like what my gut told me, but I wasn't sure. Thanks! Using `-XTypeApplications` is rather tedious, but it works: https://github.com/sgraf812/pomaps/blob/6d077d3413c3fcc0de05955c2d6b9bd82c085a85/library/Data/POSet/Internal.hs

Comment: Btw., I think the third and fourth `Coercible`s are switched. Not that it changes anything about the idea.

Comment: @SebastianGraf, if you're wrapping a whole module, you may find it easier to use full type signatures than type applications.  `foo = coerce (M.foo :: theoldthing this that) :: forall this that. thenewthing this that)`. More copy/paste that way, with less thinking about which type arguments go where.

Answer (score 1):

The solution with `TypeApplications` is quite straightforward:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import Data.Coerce
import qualified Data.Map as M

newtype Set a = Set (M.Map a ())

member :: Ord a => a -> Set a -> Bool
member = coerce (M.member @_ @())

union :: Ord a => Set a -> Set a -> Set a
union = coerce (M.union @_ @())
```

Note that some functions will require more or less wildcards, e.g.

```
smap :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> Set a -> Set b
smap = coerce (M.mapKeys @_ @_ @())
```

To determine how exactly you must specify the type applications (aside from trial and error), use

```
>:set -fprint-explicit-foralls
>:i M.mapKeys
M.mapKeys ::
  forall k2 k1 a. Ord k2 => (k1 -> k2) -> M.Map k1 a -> M.Map k2 a
```

The variable order you get from `:i` is the same one used by `TypeApplications`.

Note that you can't use `coerce` for `fromList` - it isn't a limitation, it just doesn't make sense:

```
fromList :: Ord a => [a] -> Set a
fromList = coerce (M.fromList @_ @())
```

This gives the error

```
* Couldn't match representation of type `a' with that of `(a, ())'
```

The best you can do here is probably

```
fromList :: Ord a => [a] -> Set a
fromList = coerce (M.fromList @_ @()) . map (flip (,) ())
```

Comment: NB: the OP is explicit that they are aware of the TypeApplications solution, but I think it's 'simple enough' - so this answer is essentially "no, there is no more elegant way". But this seems largely opinion based, so instead I phrase the answer itself as a (simple!) method which can be used to mechanically write such code without thinking hard about how to do so.

Comment: `:set -fprint-explicit-foralls` sounds like what I had reached for if I had known it when implementing https://github.com/sgraf812/pomaps/blob/6d077d3413c3fcc0de05955c2d6b9bd82c085a85/library/Data/POSet/Internal.hs. Thanks for your tips, but I think the other post is a more direct answer to the question.